# Macro to allocate struct on stack with pre-computed member lengths

Tags: c, macros, struct

I have a struct of the form:

```
typedef struct node {
  unsigned int * keys;
  unsigned int * branches;
} NODE;
```

The number of keys and branches is determined at runtime, but is known.  It is derived from another struct:

```
typedef struct tree {
  unsigned int num_keys_per_node;
} TREE;
```

In order to allocate a `NODE` for this `TREE`, the manual steps would be:

```
NODE node;
unsigned int keys[tree->num_keys_per_node];
unsigned int branches[tree->num_keys_per_node + 1];

node.keys     = keys;
node.branches = branches;
```

I need to allocate a lot of these nodes inside tight loops, only temporarily as I traverse a data structure, discarding them quickly as the node traversal continues.  I could write a function that returns a pointer and `malloc()` the keys and branches on the heap and `free()` them manually, but I'd prefer to use the stack if possible.

Since this initialization logic is going to be repeated in a number of places, how can I define a macro, so that I can effectively do something like:

```
NODE node = CREATE_NODE_FOR_TREE(tree);
```

I'm having difficultly seeing a way to do this which will result in the preprocessor giving a valid syntax.

Happy to hear other approaches to dynamic struct allocation on stack memory too.

EDIT | I should never need more than one node in memory at the same time, so I can re-use the one struct repeatedly too.

Comment: You have two errors in your code regarding the addressing of `keys` and `branches`. As they are arrays you do not need to use the `&` operator to get their addresses.

Comment: Oops, yeah, that's a typo, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `node` as argument to the macro like so:

```
#define CREATE_NODE_FOR_TREE( \
  node, \
  tree) \
  \
  unsigned int keys[tree->num_keys_per_node]; \
  unsigned int branches[tree->num_keys_per_node + 1]; \
  \
  node.keys     = keys; \
  node.branches = branches; 

...
NODE node = {0};
CREATE_NODE_FOR_TREE(node, tree);
...
```

This solution assumes at least c99.

Answer (score 1):

Compound literals can't be VLA and your size parameter is dynamic, so there is no possibility to do that directly with the syntax that you propose. I'd do the following:

```
#define NODE_ON_STACK(NAME, TREE)                         \
NODE NAME = { 0 };                                        \
register size_t NAME ## keys = (TREE)->num_keys_per_node; \
auto unsigned int NAME ## keys[NAME ## keys];             \
auto unsigned int NAME ## branches[NAME ## keys + 1];     \
node.keys     = NAME ## keys;                             \
node.branches = NAME ## branches
```

This works at any place in function scope where several declarations can be placed. `register` and `auto` ensure that it is never used in file scope. The `NAME ## keys` variable ensures that the `TREE` argument is only evaluated once. You also could mangle the names of the identifiers that are generated a bit more to avoid conflicts, if you like.

Nitpicks:

- always initialize `struct` variables
- your `TREE` thing got somehow wrong in the question
- the `&` operator in your question was wrong
- `int` as an integer type is almost certainly wrong, things that are counting stuff should  be `unsigned`
- `unsigned int` is also wrong, `size_t` is usually best for everything
  that is supposed to count objects or parts of it.

Ah and the usual warning tag: VLA as `auto` variables are to be taken carefully because of stackoverflow. But you knew that already, I suppose.

Comment: wow. `register` and `auto` keywords. I've never seen it on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like the following might work, though I'm not sure if it's the best way to do this:

```
#define PASTE2(x,y) x##y
#define PASTE(x,y)  PASTE2(x,y)

#define CREATE_NODE_FOR_TREE( n, tree) \
    NODE n;                         \
    unsigned int PASTE(n,_keys)[(tree)->num_keys_per_node];         \
    unsigned int PASTE(n,_branches)[(tree)->num_keys_per_node + 1]; \
    n.keys     = &PASTE(n,_keys);                                \
    n.branches = &PASTE(n,_branches);
```

The token pasting is there so that if at some point you needed to use more than one `NODE` at a time, the 'hidden' `keys` and `branches` locals would have their names 'scoped' to the `NODE` name to avoid a conflict.
To use it, instead of

```
NODE node = CREATE_NODE_FOR_TREE(tree);
```

You'd declare and initialize `node` like so:

```
CREATE_NODE_FOR_TREE(node, tree);
```